# AngularJS ui-router clashes with OAuth2 access_token

Tags: angularjs, oauth

I have a front-end developed in AngularJS with ui-router. To consume the REST API from the backend I need to get an OAuth2 access token (implicit grant).

My problem lies in the last step of the OAuth dance, when I get the access token back from the authentication server in the url

```
mydomain.com/home/#access_token=hdzjkdnba89fenbjkéz38U0D903ç&...
```

`mydomain.com/home` being the redirect URI, obviously.

Just a fraction of second after the redirection, AngularJS changes the URL in something like

```
mydomain.com/#/my-default-view
```

and consequently the access token is erased from the URL.

A few things now:

- I am not allowed to define a redirect URI containing a hash ('#') for my OAuth2 client. Hence something like `mydomain.com/#/auth-complete/` would **not** be OK.
- I use `$routeProvider.otherwise('/')`.
- I tried to set `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` to remove the '#' in the middle but the problem is the same (the URL and the access token are erased instantly after redirection).
- As the access token is still accessible in the HTTP response even after the URL is modified by Angular, I could probably use an `$http` interceptor but that sounds a bit too much for this common task isn't it?

Any advice?

Comment: Probably you might do not have a matching state for the auth URL. Since you have $routeProvider.otherwise('/'), unmatched url patterns will forwarded to root of the web site.

Comment: But how do I match a url containing an arbitrary token? Is is possible to use something like regex to say "if the url contains 'access_token', just don't do anything"?

Comment: Yes you can have regex matching. Check the documentation here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

Comment: Oh man... Sorry I didn't see that. Thanks ;-)

Comment: Would you please share how you solve this in code? I am having exactly same issue. Thanks

Comment: Ping @Buddyshot, did you made it? The solution below doesn't do the trick, apparently, I've tried here too.

Comment: I just posted an answer. Hope it's still working, I'm not using `ui-router` anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not using `ui-router` anymore but for those who still need a workaround, you just have to catch the token in a regex. From [the documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing), you can do something like

```
.state('oauth.token', {
        url: "/o/#{authToken:[0-9a-zA-Z]+}",
        ...
 })
```

and get your access token in `authToken`.

Comment: can you elaborate on your answer?

Answer (score 5):

This one works for me with Google as OAuth2 provider for Client-side Applications:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

$stateProvider.state('access_token', {
    url: '/access_token={accessToken}&token_type={tokenType}&expires_in={expiresIn}',
    template: '',
    controller: function($stateParams) {
        var token = $stateParams.accessToken;
        // do something usefull with token
    }
})
```